# Datagrip expand column list to new line with comma at beginning

Tags: sql, datagrip

In DataGrip, I want to expand the column list of a `SELECT *` and put every item onto a new line with a comma at the beginning. This would involve a combination of code style settings.

However, when setting the "Place comma" style to "To beginning", the items in the list no longer appear on a new line each - they appear in one line.

Is it possible in DataGrip for each expanded item to appear on a new line prefixed with a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like just a bug. Filed it in the issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-20230/Setting-Place-comma-style-to-To-beginning-breaks-chopping

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have regex replacement available, you could try something as simple as:

```
Find:    ,\s*
Replace: ,\n
```

But you would need to make sure that you are only targeting the `SELECT` clause.  If there were other CSV lists of columns, the above would replace those too.  Check the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Kc8L9d/1).

Comment: Not quite looking for a 2 step system. I could use DataGrip's formatting hotkey to apply the desired format after the one-line expansion, but I'm looking to do this on the expansion itself in 1 step.

Comment: A regex replacement is just a single step, right?  How does your tool work?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your answer, you've suggested using a text editor Find->Replace with regex to break the single-line items into multiple lines prefixed with commas. DataGrip itself has a coding style setting which should already accomplish this with a keystroke. 

However, enabling it seems to break the feature to expand `SELECT *` into all the tables' columns to one line each.

What I'm looking for is to fix the unwanted behaviour of expand column list (step 1) while maintaining commas at the start of items without fixing the list with Find->Replace or formatting (step 2)